# owin oauth webapi with a dynamic TokenEndpointPath (request for example)

Tags: owin

I refer to post of David Snipp in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29706891/4609861 to kindly ask a little example of his explanation; I am having troubles calling delegate OnMatchEndpoint and the MatchesTokenEndpoint. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the delegates on Options itself in your Startup.cs code. Something along these lines:

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
{
      provider = new OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider()
      {
        OnMatchEndpoint = (context =>
                                  { // do your stuff
                                   context.MatchesAuthorizationEndpoint();
                                   return Task.FromResult<object>(0);
                                   });
      }
 }
```

Comment: sorry but I am not able to get out...
PublicClientId = "self";
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions {
  TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/v1/Token"),
  Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId) {
    OnMatchEndpoint = ( context => { 
      // my code
      context.MatchesAuthorizationEndpoint();
    })
  },
  AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
  AllowInsecureHttp = true
}

Comment: under:  context => {     i get "Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'System.Func<Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthMatchEndpointContext,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'"

Comment: under:  MatchesAuthorizationEndpoint()  I get 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthMatchEndpointContext' does not contain a definition for 'MatchesAuthorizationEndpoint' and no extension method 'MatchesAuthorizationEndpoint' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthMatchEndpointContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is `ApplicationOAuthProvider` a custom class? The error under context should go away with the return statement that I added.

Comment: yes it's inherited from OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and overrides: GrantResourceOwnerCredentials TokenEndpoint ValidateClientAuthentication and ValidateClientRedirectUri

Comment: Did adding return Task.FromResult<object>(0); fixed the error on context?  I don't understand why it will give Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthMatchEndpointContext' does not contain a definition for 'MatchesAuthorizationEndpoint' error. The property exists in Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthMatchEndpointContext. Could you copy your complete .cs file here

Comment: I changed MatchesAuthorizationEndpoint() to MatchesAuthorizeEndpoint() and it worked.